# Is the field of invertible complex linear operators algebraically closed?

Tags: linear-algebra, field-theory

I am reading Axler's Linear Algebra Done Right and he proved every invertible linear complex operator has a square root. Following the prove one can show that they have any n-th root, hence I wonder if the stronger algebraically closed condition fulfills too. I have absolutely no idea how to tackle such problem.

In other words, let $T$ be an invertible operator in $\mathcal L(V)$, $P$ be a complex polynomial, is there an invertible operator $S$ such that $P(S)=T$.

Comment: I'm not awfully familiar with this concept. Is it a field in the first place?

Comment: The square root of an operator exists only if the operator is positive..are you sure it's not part of the hypothesis?

Comment: @John117: in $\mathbb{R}$, yes, but the OP states it’s over $\mathbb{C}$. But note that the ring of linear complex operators isn’t commutative – and the space of invertible complex operators isn’t even a group for addition – so it’s not exactly clear which notion of algebraic closure the OP refers to. Maybe the following question: let $A$ be a $n\times n$ matrix, $P$ be a complex polynomial, is there a matrix $B$ such that $P(B)=A$?

Comment: @Mindlack I didn't know there were multiple notions under the same name. I did mean exactly that. I will edit the question accordingly.

Comment: Actually there’s only one real definition of algebraic closure, but it *really* doesn’t apply as is – so you’re forced to be more specific with what you want to prove.

Comment: Shouldn't both matrices $A,B$ be invertible as well for this question to make any sense?

Comment: I'm sorry, I made it precise that the operators must be invertible, I wrote it on the title but forgot to put it in the last formulation.

Comment: For invertible operators, this isn't even true for linear polynomials. Take $P=x+1$ and $T = J_1$, where $J_1$ is some non-trivial Jordan block with eigenvalue $1$.

Comment: @EuYu if you write that as an answer I will mark it as the solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For invertible operators, this isn't even true for linear polynomials. For a simple counterexample, take $p(x) = x+1$ and let
$$T = \begin{pmatrix}1&1\\0&1\end{pmatrix}.$$

Answer (score 3):

The answer is no.

Take $A=\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{pmatrix}$. Then $A$ isn't a square : there's no matrix $B$ such that $B^2=A$.

Indeed, such a matrix would commute with $A$. But
$$\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}c&d\\0&0\end{pmatrix}$$ while

$$\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}0&a\\0&c\end{pmatrix}$$

Therefore if such a matrix existed, it would be upper triangular (i.e. $c$ would be $0$).

But if its square is $A$ then it's diagonal must be $0$ as well (i.e. $a=d=0$).

But then, its square would be the null matrix, not $A$.

**Edit** : asking for invertible matrix doesn't change the answer.

Just take $A'=I_2+A=\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$ and $P=X^2+1$. Then $$P(B)=A'\Longleftrightarrow B^2=A$$ which is impossible for the reasons explained above.

Comment: Thanks. I'm sorry but just corrected the question to ask about only invertible operators.

Comment: @Shiranai : Hi. I've edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

I feel obligated to complete Ayoub’s answer. The answer is indeed no, but it’s *almost* true (discounting the invertibility requirements added later, which are addressed in a comment) in the following sense: if the eigenvalues of $A$ each have one pre-image by $P$ which isn’t a root of $P’$, then it’s true.

Why? We can assume that $A$ is triangular by blocks, and all blocks have the diagonal of a scalar matrix. Clearly, we only need to solve for each block, and thus assume that $A=\alpha I+N$, $N$ nilpotent upper triangular and $\alpha \in P((P’)^{-1}(\mathbb{C}^{\times}))$. Write $\alpha=P(\beta)$ with $P’(\beta)\neq 0$, we search for a solution of the form $B=\beta I+N’$ with $N’$ nilpotent and upper triangular.

Then the equation can be re-written $P_1(N’)=N$, where $P_1$ is a complex polynomial such that $P_1(0)=0 \neq P_1’(0)$.
It can be shown by induction (ie find an explicit recursive formula on the coefficients) that there is a formal power series $f$ such that $P_1(f(T))=T$ and $f(0)=0$. Thus, if $f(T)=Q(T)+T^{n+1}g(T)$, where $g$ is a formal power series and $Q$ is a polynomial, $T^{n+1}|P_1(Q(T))-T$.

Thus by Cayley-Hamilton $N’=Q(N)$ works.

Comment: Thanks. I'm sorry but just corrected the question to ask about only invertible operators. Furthermore, what is $P'$ here? The derivative? I am not familiar with your notation, what does $\alpha \in P((P’)^{-1}(\mathbb{C}^{\times}))$ mean here? I am not sure what a scalar being in a polynomial means.

Comment: Invertible operators don’t significantly change my answer (and I’d expect the general case to be a more natural question). You just need to be able to choose $\beta \neq 0$, so it would be “the eigenvalues of $A$ are in $P((P’)^{-1}(\mathbb{C}^{\times})\backslash \{0\})$. In my original answer, it’s a set-theoretical notation, where $P’$ is indeed the derivative of the polynomial: $(P’)^{-1}(\mathbb{C}^{\times})$ is the set $S$ of elements $t \in \mathbb{C}$ such that $P’(t) \in \mathbb{C}^{\times}$. Then $P(S)$ is the set of the $P(t)$ with $t \in S$.